# Apply changes to Map values using Java 8 Streams

Tags: collections, filter, java-8, java-stream

I want to change Map values using java 8.

```
Map<String, String> attributeMap = new TreeMap<>();
attributeMap.put("C","FIRSTNAMe");
attributeMap.put("C3","1111");
attributeMap.put("C4","ABCNAMe");
```

After the changes, the output as a string should look like

```
c='FIRSTNAMe',c3=111,c4='ABCNAMe'
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: `attributeMap.toString()` doesn't do the job?

Comment: NO .@SzymonStepniak . I want to check condtion for value and make changes into . You can see in to out put.

Comment: what kind of condition, what changes? Please explain in code

Comment: Take example if value is equal to 1111 than value doesn't contains single quotes other wice all value shoube inside single quotes.

Comment: @valamanoj What have you tried so far? What kind of problem do you have with the code you have wrote?

Comment: I have write but using java7

Comment: for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : attributeMap.entrySet()) {
    columns += entry.getKey() + "," ; 
    values = entry.getValue();
    if(values.equalsIgnoreCase("11111"))
     test += values + ",";
    else
     test += '\''+  values + '\''+ "," ;
    
  }

Comment: i want to use JAVA 8 to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method `transform` and pass a `Predicate` for when to quote or not:

```
public static String tranform(Map<String, String> attributeMap, Predicate<String> predicate) {
    return attributeMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.mapping(e -> {
                return e.getKey().toLowerCase() + "=" +
                        (predicate.test(e.getValue()) ? "'" + e.getValue() + "'" : e.getValue());
            }, Collectors.joining(",")));
}
```

And call it like this:

```
String result = tranform(attributeMap, "1111"::equals);
System.out.println(result); // c=FIRSTNAMe,c3='1111',c4=ABCNAMe
```

If you want to quote only numbers, just use a different `Predicate`:

```
Predicate<String> predicate = s -> s.matches("\\d+");
String result = tranform(attributeMap, predicate);
```

Comment: It possible to seperate key and value into string value like as c,c3,c4,FIRSTNAMe,'1111',ABCNAMe

Comment: @valamanoj you are asking if it is possible? One single String or two?

Comment: yes , I dont knw i have tried but give me error into single string